# Can't map component prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, storybook

I am passing props to my component that link to [storybook](https://storybook.js.org/). Problem is object that i pass in is don't map. and it says

`"TypeError: data.map is not a function"`.

So i think my object is not an "array" yet and i tried fix until code look like this.

**Works.mocks.ts**

```
import { ImgixImage } from '@/model/storage';
import { IWorks } from './Works';

const base: IWorks = [
  {
    projectID: 1,
    projectName: 'Project - 1',
    projectPic: { url: ImgixImage.main_portfolio1, width: 360, height: 480 },
    projectDesc:
      'Project - 1 || Photo booth fam kinfolk cold-pressed sriracha leggings jianbing microdosing tousled waistcoat.',
  },
  {
    projectID: 2,
    projectName: 'Project - 2',
    projectPic: { url: ImgixImage.main_portfolio2, width: 360, height: 480 },
    projectDesc:
      'Project - 2 || Photo booth fam kinfolk cold-pressed sriracha leggings jianbing microdosing tousled waistcoat.',
  },
  {
    projectID: 3,
    projectName: 'Project - 3',
    projectPic: {
      url: 'https://dummyimage.com/720x400',
      width: 360,
      height: 480,
    },
    projectDesc:
      'Project - 3 || Photo booth fam kinfolk cold-pressed sriracha leggings jianbing microdosing tousled waistcoat.',
  },
];

export const mockWorksProps = {
  base,
};
```

**Works.tsx**

```
import Image from 'next/image';

interface project {
  projectID: number;
  projectName: string;
  projectPic: { url: string; width: number; height: number };
  projectDesc: string;
}

export interface IWorks extends Array<project> {}

const Works: React.FC<IWorks> = (works: IWorks) => {
  const data = works;
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="">
        <div className="">
          {data.map(({ projectID, projectName, projectPic, projectDesc }) => (
            <div key={projectID} className="">
              <div className="">
                <Image
                  className=""
                  src={projectPic.url}
                  width={projectPic.width}
                  height={projectPic.height}
                  alt="https://dummyimage.com/360x480"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Works;
```

**Works.stories.tsx**

```
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from '@storybook/react';
import Works, { IWorks } from './Works';
import { mockWorksProps } from './Works.mocks';

export default {
  title: 'templates/Works',
  component: Works,
  argTypes: {},
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Works>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Works> = (args) => <Works {...args} />;

export const Base = Template.bind({});

Base.args = {
  ...mockWorksProps.base,
} as IWorks;
```

What is need to fix prop as an "array" ?
Help of any kind is much appreciated

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Creating the files on my local machine just works. It could be something else like some `tsconfig.json` setting or the Typescript version being used. Would you please [edit] your question and add both the `tsconfig.json` and the `package.json`?

Comment: If `mockWorksProps` is meant to be the props that are passed to the component, then shouldn't it be declared as `export const mockWorksProps = { works: base };`? You would then spread that into the args directly: `Base.args = { ...mockWorksProps } as IWorks;`. Finally, you should modify the `Works` component to expect a props argument: `const Works = ({ works }: { works: IWorks }) => {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components take a props object as an argument, not direct prop value. In `Works` you've named the *entire* props object `works`. `works` should instead be a property ***of*** the props object.

```
interface project {
  projectID: number;
  projectName: string;
  projectPic: { url: string; width: number; height: number };
  projectDesc: string;
}

export interface IWorks {
  works: Array<project>;
}

const Works: React.FC<IWorks> = ({ works }: IWorks) => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="">
        <div className="">
          {works.map(({ projectID, projectName, projectPic, projectDesc }) => (
            <div key={projectID} className="">
              <div className="">
                <Image
                  className=""
                  src={projectPic.url}
                  width={projectPic.width}
                  height={projectPic.height}
                  alt="https://dummyimage.com/360x480"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

...

```
import { ComponentMeta, ComponentStory } from '@storybook/react';
import Works, { IWorks } from './Works';
import { mockWorksProps } from './Works.mocks';

export default {
  title: 'templates/Works',
  component: Works,
  argTypes: {},
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Works>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Works> = (args) => <Works {...args} />;

export const Base = Template.bind({});

Base.args = {
  works: mockWorksProps.base, // <-- pass a works prop
} as IWorks;
```